# asp.net mvc - implementing an "autocomplete" tags selection for a blog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, tags, tagging

I'm working on a blog system for my own use, and would like to implement an auto-complete tags selection (similar to stackoverflow), how would I implement something like this? Any example or links to a tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've decided to give jQuery UI Autocomplete a try and it seems to be easy enough :) Here's the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $("#TagsString")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.get("/Blog/GetTags", { term: extractLast(request.term) }, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.tags, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Id
                            }
                        }))
                    }, "json");
                },
                minLength: 2,
                dataType: 'json',
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.label);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<p>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.TagsString, new { @tabindex = "2", @size = "22", @value = "", @class = "text_input" })
            <label for="TagsString">
                <strong class="leftSpace">Tags</strong></label></p>
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading
    {
        background: white url('/Content/Images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

And here's the action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual JsonResult GetTags(string term)
        {
            var getTags = _tag.All().Where(t => t.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList();

            TagViewModel model = new TagViewModel()
            {
                Tags = Mapper.Map<List<Tag>, List<TagModel>>(getTags)
            };

            return Json(new
            {
                tags = model.Tags
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Works really well :)

Comment: Yes eth0, sorry for not mentioned it :) Should have said "... largely based on eth0's code".

Answer (score 7):

See my question here [Jquery, Autocomplete using json, id's vs display values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210550/jquery-autocomplete-using-json-ids-vs-display-values)

We actually "borrowed" (read copy and pasted) SO's autocomplete javascript and then tweaked it slightly - such as renaming it so it won't interfere with [jquery ui's autocomplet](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)e.

The two are actually very similar, but we wanted specifically to have a tag system like SO.

you can yank the code I used off http://pastebin.com/t29RCCZg

and here is a sample action we used for tags

```
public ActionResult ProfileTags(string prefix, int? limit)
    {
        if (!limit.HasValue)
            limit = ConfigurationHelper.Paging.TagList;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
            prefix = String.Empty;

        ProfileTagModel model = new ProfileTagModel()
        {
            Tags = profileTagRepository.GetList(new ProfileTagsByPrefixQuery(prefix)).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Take<ProfileTag>(limit.Value)
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

And the view looks like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ProfileTagModel>" %>

<% if(Model.Tags != null) { %>
    <% foreach (ProfileTag tag in Model.Tags) { %>
        <%= tag.Name + ((tag.ProfileCount > 0) ? " (" + tag.ProfileCount.ToString() + ")" : String.Empty) %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

And then our usage on the page looks something like this

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#ProfileTags").troppinautocomplete('<%= Url.Action("ProfileTags", "Filter") %>', {
        max: 10,
        highlightItem: true,
        multiple: true,
        multipleSeparator: " ",
        matchContains: false,
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300,
        dataType: "html"
    });


})
```

You don't have to do it this way, though.  You can make the action method return an array of objects as json, and then by altering how your autocomplete is declared, you can actually format the tags in to display with an icon or other features.

Heres a sample that took in json for a formatted look

```
$('#troppinSearch').troppinautocomplete(url, {
        dataType: 'json',
        parse: function (data) {
            var rows = new Array();
            if (data != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Id, result: data[i].Title };
                }
            }
            return rows;
        },
        formatItem: function (row, i, n) {

            return '<table><tr><td valign="top"><img height="28" width="28" src="' + row.ImageUrl + '" /></td><td valign="top" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 6px;"><div>' + row.Title + '</div><div><small>' + row.ResultType + '</small></div></td></tr></table>';
        },
        formatResult: function (row, i, n) {
            return row.Id;
        },
        width: 336,
        max: 20,
        highlightItem: true,
        multiple: false,
        matchContains: true,
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 300
    }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        var type = data.ResultType.toLowerCase();
        var id = data.Id;

        if (type == "product") {
            window.location.href = '/Shop/Product/' + id;
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/Profile/Index/' + id;
        }
    });
```

And the action looks like this

```
public ActionResult Search(string contentType, string prefix, int? limit)
    {
        if (!limit.HasValue)
            limit = ConfigurationHelper.Paging.ProfileList;

        SearchResponse response = GetSearchResults(contentType, prefix);

        var dropDownResults = (from r in response.Results
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = r.Id,
                                  Title = r.Name,
                                  ImageUrl = r.DefaultImage,
                                  ResultType = r.ResultType.ToString()
                              }).Distinct().Take(limit.Value);

        return Json(dropDownResults.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When you do it this way, you don't need a view.  The autocompleter takes in the json data and does everything magically.  The .Result function on the end lets you set up an event that occurs when a selection is made.  in this case it's actually sending the user to another page, but we have used it to set a value in a hidden field.

**EDIT**

I forgot the built in CSS classes for this code.  Here's a sample CSS.

```
.ac_results{
padding:0;
border:1px solid #4c4c4c;
background-color:#ffffff;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:99999;
text-align:left;
font-size: 14px; line-height:14px;
color: #333333;
}

.ac_highlight{
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline;
background-color: #ff6600;
color: #ffffff;
}

.ac_results ul{
width:100%;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;

}

.ac_results li{
margin:0;
padding:3px 6px 3px 6px;
cursor:default;
display:block;
line-height:14px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.ac_loading{
background:#fff url(/Content/images/loading.gif) right center no-repeat;

}

.ac_over{
background-color:#ff6600;
color:#ffffff;

}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I'll try your code soon and hopefully it'll work out. A question on your code, does it allow multiple tags like what SO supports? Thanks.

Comment: The top one does, yes.  There is an option called multiple and it is set to true. The separator is a space, just like on SO.

Comment: Hi Josh, can you elaborate a little bit on these models and methods: `ProfileTagModel`, `ProfileTagsByPrefixQuery`, and the `GetList` method from the repository? And also, are you returning that ProfileTags as a view, or a partial view? Thanks again.

Comment: ProfileTags is afull view.  `ProfileTagModel` is just a class that I use as my model.  The `ProfileTagsByPrefixQuery` is a class that is used in `GetList` to turn a linq expression into linq to nhibernate.  The gist of that is to get your tags by doing a search on the value passed in to the controller.  How you get those tags is up to your data model.  Mine happens to be using linq to nhibernate with a repository model.

Comment: I can't seems to make it work, here's my workflow: 1) Copied the CSS styles to my stylesheet. 2) Copied the js from the Pastebin and named it tageditor.js, included that in the page. Create a new ActionResult called BlogTags inside Blog Controller, create a View called BlogTags inside Blog Views folder. In my main "Create" view where I can create a new blog post, I have a input textbox with Id = BlogTags, and then I uses this script `$("#BlogTags").troppinautocomplete('<%= Url.Action("/Blog/BlogTags", "Filter") ... `. But this doesn't do anything to fire up the autocomplete. Any idea? THanks.

Comment: Oh, I know why.  You must add a route for `"BlogTags/{limit}/{prefix}"`.  And you can test to make sure it works by hitting the url in your browser.

Comment: I can hit the URL directly from the browser and able to retrieve the tags, but in the page where I create a new post, with the textbox where I would like to autocomplete search for tags, typing anything in there doesn't trigger the script `...troppinautocomplete(...` at all. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you wrapped the autocomplete call in a `$(function () { });`

Comment: I've already have that `$().ready(function() { ... .. });` block around the `troppinautocomplete` code. :(

Answer (score 3):

I use jQuery UI's autocomplete but I load the data beforehand;

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Tags, new { @class = "txtbox-long" })
@Html.Resource(@<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.11.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />, "css")
@Html.Resource(@<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/JS/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>, "js")
@Html.Resource(
    @<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var tags; $.getJSON("/Thread/GetTags", function (data) { tags = data; });

             function split(val) { return val.split(/ \s*/); }
             function extractLast(term) { return split(term).pop(); }

             $("#Tags")
             // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) event.preventDefault();
                })
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, extractLast(request.term)));
                    },
                    focus: function () {
                        // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        // add placeholder to get the space at the end
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(" ");

                        return false;
                    }
                });
         });
    </script>
, "js")
```

Controller:

```
[Classes.Attributes.Ajax]
public JsonResult GetTags()
{
    return Json(
        TagService.GetTags().Select(x => x.Name),
        "text/plain",
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Works really well and saves multiple calls to the database as it uses client side searching. I'm using it in a small project so there won't be that many tags.

Answer (score 1):

You could call an Action Method that would take the text they're currently entering and return a View with a populated list of possible tags.

Your Action Method could look like this:

```
public ActionResult GetTags(string tag)
{
    List<string> tags = // get AutoComplete data from somewhere

    return View(tags);
}
```

And your Autocomplete View could simply be:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<IList<string>>" %>

<ul>
    <% foreach(string tag in Model) { %>
    <li><%=tag %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

And if you're using jQuery, you could try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Autocomplete/GetTags/" + tag,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $("#autocomplete").html(html);
    }
});
```